# How to download pages that end in a certain way with httrack?

Tags: httrack

I was trying to download certain pages that end in a certain phrase. I looked through the documentation and couldn't find out how. If there is or isn't a way please tell me and if so how.

EDIT: Say for example I am trying to get these websites:
`example.com/sdfsdfs/awrf235/sdgsdg/important_page.html
example.com/sdfsasdasddfs/awrfg235/sdgsdg/important_page.html
example.com/sdfsdfsdfs/awrf235g/sdsagsdg/important_page.html`

And there are 100 more of those that end in /important_page.html
and 1000 more of other useless stuff. How could I download the ones that end just in /important_page.html

Comment: Can you provide more information.  Describe more what you are trying to accomplish (example), the obsticles and the things you have tried so far.

Comment: in general, is the format of what you're trying to scrape
`example.com/RANDOM/RANDOM/important_page.html` (i.e., `example.com` and `important_page.html` are fixed and the other parts fo the path can vary?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Options / Scan Rules`, click *Include link(s)* and then add a scan rule for the filename you want to match:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]
(The image above shows an exclusion rule being added, but the UI's the same for inclusion rules as well.)

Documentation for [filters/scan rules](http://www.httrack.com/html/step9_opt4.html) and [advanced filters](http://www.httrack.com/html/filters.html).